# Modeling a two tank system which will be regulated using a single valve

Tags: fluid-mechanics, control-engineering

This is a mix between a physics and controls engineering question. At first I thought it was mostly a physics question and I therefore asked it at physics stack exchange. But they said this was mostly a controls engineering problem, so I am asking the question here. My problem lies in understanding in how the fluid will act in the system. I got thrown into this problem without really knowing anything about fluid dynamics. I have been reading up, but I am still uncertain on a lot of this stuff.

I have the following challenge:

> Create a system consisting of two separate tanks. There is water flowing into one of the tanks (tank 1) which then flows from tank 1 into a second tank (tank 2). The water then flows out from tank 2. Create a two tank system where you regulate the water height in tank 2 using a single valve. You can form the system however you want as long as these requirements are met.

There was three possible design-ideas I had in mind:

1.

[image: Tank 1 higher than tank 2 with a valve in the pipe before tank 1]

This is how I would describe this system mathematically (please tell me if I have misunderstood something):

I would be able to regulate the input flow using the valve. Lets look at the valve itself first:
This is a drawing of the valve:

[image: Drawing of the valve]

Assuming the water is incompressible and inviscid. You apply Bernoulli's equation:

$$P_1 + \frac{ρv_1 ^ 2}{2} + ρgh_1 = P_2 + \frac{ρv_2 ^ 2}{2} + ρgh_2 $$

$pgh_1 = pgh_2$ since the each side of the valve is on the same height which gives:

I $$P_1 + \frac{ρv_1 ^ 2}{2} = P_2 + \frac{ρv_2 ^ 2}{2} $$

Since the water is incompressible, the mass flow on each side of the valve is the same:

II $$ω_1 = ω_2 \iff ρA_1v_1 = ρA_2v_2 \iff v_1 = \frac{A_2}{A_1}v_2$$

Combining the results from equation 1 and 2 gives that:

$$v_2 = \sqrt{\frac{2(P_1-P_2)}{ρ(1-(\frac{A_2}{A_1})^2)}}$$

And that:

$$ω_2 = ρA_2\sqrt{\frac{2(P_1-P_2)}{ρ(1-(\frac{A_2}{A_1})^2)}}$$

The mass flow into the first tank $ω_{in1}$ is equivalent to $ω_2$.This means the mass flow into the first tank could be controlled by varying $A_2$.

The mass-change in tank 1 can be written as:

$$\dot{m_1} = ω_{in1} - ω_{out1}$$

$ω_{out1}$ can be written as a function of the height h_1 in the following way:

The tanks are open and I am assuming the pressure at the output of tank 1 is the same as the atmospheric pressure over the water in tank 1 (call this $P_0$). Bernoulli's equation gives:

$$P_0 + \frac{ρv_1 ^ 2}{2} + ρgh_1 = P_0 + \frac{ρv_2 ^ 2}{2} + ρgh_2$$

where $v_1$ and $v_2$ is the velocity of the liquids at the top of tank 1 and at the output of tank 1 respectively. $h_1$ and $h_2$ are the heights of the liquids at the top and output of tank 1 respectively. A lot of people online say that since the area of the tank is much larger than the area of the pipe, the velocity $v_1$ can be approximated to zero. Which makes sense, but how much of a simplification is this? Setting $v_1 = 0$ gives:

$$ρgh_1 =\frac{ρv_2 ^ 2}{2} + ρgh_2 \iff v_2 = \sqrt{2g(h_1-h_2)}$$

Since the heights $h_1$ and $h_2$ are relative I am letting $h_2 = 0$:

$$v_2 = \sqrt{2gh_1} \iff ω_{out1} = ρA_{p1}\sqrt{2gh_1}$$
where $A_{p1}$ is the cross sectional area of the pipe going from tank 1 to tank 2.

Let $A_{b1}$ be the bottom area of tank 1 which is constant for all heights of the tank. You have that:

$$\dot{m_1} = ρA_{b1}\dot{h_1}$$

which means that:

$$\dot{h_1} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b1}}(ω_{in1}-ω_{out1})$$
where:
$$ω_{in1} = ρA_2\sqrt{\frac{2(P_1-P_2)}{ρ(1-(\frac{A_2}{A_1})^2)}}$$
and:
$$ω_{out1} = ρA_{p1}\sqrt{2gh_1}$$

A lot of the same principle's can be used for tank 2 and you also have:

$$\dot{h_2} = \frac{1}{ρA_{b2}}(ω_{in2}-ω_{out2})$$
where $A_{b2}$ is the bottom area of tank 2 and:
$$ω_{in2} = ω_{out1} = ρA_{p1}\sqrt{2gh_1}$$
Using the exact same logic used to derive $ω_{out1}$ applied on $ω_{out2}$ you get:
$$ω_{out2} = ρA_{p2}\sqrt{2gh_2}$$

These differential equations could be used to build a regulating system. But is my logic correct and are the equations above applicable for a real life system? Are there any other factors which I should be accounting for? Should I for example model the viscosity of the water? One possible problem with this system is that there will be quite some transport delay from the valve to tank 2.

2.
This is another possible design:

[image: Tank 1 higher than tank 2 with a valve in between them]

But I am wondering if this in reality is a one tank system (which means its invalid for this challenge) if you look at the input of tank 1 and tank 1 itself as a single pipe. I tried using Bernoulli's equation to show this was the case, but was not able to. Is it true that this in reality acts like a one tank system? And how can you show that?

3.
Another possible design could be one where the valve is placed in between two tanks at the same height like this:

[image: Two tanks at the same height with a single valve in between them]

At first sight I thought this system would pretty much be identical to the second system (and was therefore really a 1 tank system). And the only difference being that the liquid would move slower compared to the second system since it only moves horizontally.

So I am asking the same question for both system 2 and 3: Are these systems in reality 1 or 2 tank systems? If I am wrong, what could be a way to model them? And are they preferable over the first system? I am also wondering if my modeling of the first system was correct.

Comment: Only systems 2 and 3 make sense to me. I presume you don't have any control off incoming or outgoing water ("water flows into tank 1... and then flows out of tank 2"). If the input is pressurised, you could use system 3, but if not, only feasible option seems to be 2.